# Build a pivot out of an array built and named in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, pivot

I'm trying to reference the source data of my pivot to a name. I have the following code:

```
Set rng1 = Sheets("CALA current credit usage").Range("A1:L235")
Set rng2 = Sheets("CALA forecast credit usage").Range("A2:L235")

Dim MyArray()
TotalRows = rng1.Rows.Count + rng2.Rows.Count + 1
ReDim Preserve MyArray(1 To TotalRows, 1 To rng1.Columns.Count)

For i = 1 To rng1.Columns.Count
    For j = 1 To rng1.Rows.Count
        MyArray(j, i) = rng1.Cells(j, i)
    Next j
Next i

j = j - 1
 ''''''
For h = 1 To rng2.Columns.Count
    For w = 1 To rng2.Rows.Count
        MyArray(w + j, h) = rng2.Cells(w, h)
    Next w
Next h

ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="ResultingRange", RefersTo:=MyArray
```

But when I linked the pivot to *ResultingRange* I got:

> Data source reference not valid.

Any ideas?

Comment: This should work.  Simple examples work on my end even of fairly large size.  What does `MyArray` look like if you debug it?

Comment: AFAIK, that will not work. Pivot Table source range or cache accepts only Tables or Range or a Named Range. No a named constant or array.

Comment: thanks, i didn t know that.